# Screen not refreshing when jQuery ajax calls in process

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two screen refresh problems that may (or may not) be related. The one that I can clearly reproduce involves making a series of ajax calls. Between each call, I am updating text inside a jQuery dialog box to show progress. At the end of the process, I hide the dialog box.

When I run this code in Chrome using the debugging panel and place a breakpoint before or after each ajax call, the dialog box update properly. If I just let the code run without breaking, the screen does not refresh at all.

I have tried introducing wait loops between each ajax call, but that doesn't fix the problem. Here is an edited down version of the code:

```
$('#saving').show();
$('#savingSpan').text('Saving Analysis');
$('#savingReport').text('Saving Header: ');
$('#savingInputs').text('Saving Inputs: ');
$('#savingResults').text('Saving Results: ');
$('#savingComplete').text('Doing Cleanup: ');

wait(250);
$('#savingReport').append('Started...');
var status = saveReport();
$('#savingReport').append('Complete.');
wait(250);
$('#savingInputs').append('Started....');
status = saveInputs();
$('#savingInputs').append('Complete.');
wait(250);
$('#savingResults').append('Started....');
status = saveResults();
$('#savingResults').append('Complete.');
wait(250);
$('#savingComplete').append('Started....');
status = saveComplete();
$('#savingComplete').append('Complete.');
$('#saving').hide();
```

The other problem is that when my page initially loads, major portions of it are blank until I run the mouse over that portion of the page. Then the areas I run the mouse over appear correctly.

Comment: Ajax requests are executed asynchronously. It is not reasonable to assume they will complete in any specific amount of time. Johan's approach is valid. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: I have determined that this is a Chrome issue. The code works just fine in FireFox and Opera

Comment: Can you restrict your users to browsers other than Chrome? Chrome has nearly half the market and almost twice the market share of the next closest browser... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the ajax call to complete. The code below simulates an ajax call:

```
var foo = 1;

setTimeout(function(){
    foo = 2;
}, 250);

console.log(foo); //1
```

What you need is a callback function, to make sure the ajax call is complete:

```
function ajaxDemo(success){

    setTimeout(function(){

        foo = 2;
        success;

    }, 250);
}

var foo = 1;

ajaxDemo(function(){

    console.log(foo);
});
```

Since you tagged the question with `jQuery`, you could do something like this (assuming the version is >= 1.5):

```
var ajaxCall1 = $.ajax({ /* ... your ajax code ... */ }),
    ajaxCall2 = $.ajax({ /* ... your ajax code ... */ }),
    ajaxCall3 = $.ajax({ /* ... your ajax code ... */ });

$.when(ajaxCall1, ajaxCall2, ajaxCall3).then(function(d1, d2, d3){
      console.log(d1); //data from first ajax call
      console.log(d2); //data from second ajax call
      //etc...
}).fail(function() {
      console.log('something went wrong in at least one of the ajax calls');
});
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I am performing two successive Ajax calls. The first completes and then fires the second. The screen does not refresh until the second is complete. AND... the screen refreshes just fine in FF.